# Is there an ActionScript 3 error 1046 handler?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, error-handling

I'm talking about this error:

```
ERROR 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: CustomType
```

Where CustomType is defined in a class in an `.as` file. I know you need to import that file in order to avoid this error, but my question is, is there any error handler for this error?

I mean, is there a way to say, for example:

```
onErrorHandler {
  trace("You need to import the class!");
} else {
  private var myObject:CustomType;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error is a thrown at compile time, so no.

The `import` statement tells Flash what classes need to be compiled for your current class to function as expected. You can't write code to catch an error that is thrown at compile-time, because it doesn't compile and thus doesn't get executed.

It is the compiler's responsibility to catch these errors, not yours.

Comment: Of course my `trace` was just a very plain and mega simple example, ultra simple example of course haha, I don't intent to do just that, I just want to know how to implement this handler haha Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Metafaniel That's cool but unfortunately there is no way to handle a missing import at run-time. For your application to compile you must have all the classes used in the current context imported, otherwise Flash doesn't know what classes it is supposed to compile.